# Compilation error with struct/class defined in a function

Tags: c++

What is the problem with the following code. Because if I define the class inside the main function, the compilation fails and I don't understand the compiler error.

Test the code from [here](http://ideone.com/t7kbHm)

Comment the 1st definition of `drift_f` (outside of `main()`) and uncomment the inner definition of `drif_t` (inside the `main()` function) and the compiler will get the following error message:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:27:24: error: template argument for ‘template<class> class std::allocator’ uses local type ‘main()::drift_t’
      std::deque<drift_t> drift; drift.push_back(drift_t(0,0));drift.push_back(drift_t(-50,-50));
                        ^
prog.cpp:27:24: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class> class std::allocator’
prog.cpp:27:24: error: template argument 2 is invalid
prog.cpp:27:31: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
      std::deque<drift_t> drift; drift.push_back(drift_t(0,0));drift.push_back(drift_t(-50,-50));
                               ^
prog.cpp:27:39: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘drift’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
      std::deque<drift_t> drift; drift.push_back(drift_t(0,0));drift.push_back(drift_t(-50,-50));
                                       ^
prog.cpp:27:69: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘drift’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
      std::deque<drift_t> drift; drift.push_back(drift_t(0,0));drift.push_back(drift_t(-50,-50));

#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

    class drift_t{ //It works
      public:
        int _drift;
        int _immediateDrift;
        drift_t() : _drift(0), _immediateDrift(0) {}
        drift_t(int d, int expected) : _drift(d), _immediateDrift(expected) {}
        drift_t(const drift_t& ro) : _drift(ro._drift), _immediateDrift(ro._immediateDrift) {}
        drift_t& operator = (const drift_t& ro) { this->_drift = ro._drift; this->_immediateDrift = ro._immediateDrift; return *this; }
      } ;//*/

int main() {

    /*class drift_t{ //It doesn't works
      public:
        int _drift;
        int _immediateDrift;
        drift_t() : _drift(0), _immediateDrift(0) {}
        drift_t(int d, int expected) : _drift(d), _immediateDrift(expected) {}
        drift_t(const drift_t& ro) : _drift(ro._drift), _immediateDrift(ro._immediateDrift) {}
        drift_t& operator = (const drift_t& ro) { this->_drift = ro._drift; this->_immediateDrift = ro._immediateDrift; return *this; }
      } ;//*/

     std::deque<drift_t> drift; drift.push_back(drift_t(0,0));drift.push_back(drift_t(-50,-50));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It compile fine here. What is the error message from the compiler ??

Comment: Are you using C++11? This code compiles for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c27b407705349ae9

Comment: I use GCC C++ 4.8.1 under Ideone and 4.6.3 on my workstation. same result on both. See my last edit for more details.

Comment: Look [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/457331-why-cant-local-structure-used-vector) for a (not very convincing) explication.

Comment: Yes it's right, as often visual-studio is not compliant and it let me write that code without complaining :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the error the one that the compiler says it is? You can't use the local class for that template initialization.

Try compiling with -std=c++11 as I believe it relaxes on that.